# c# Register Global Hotkeys without hook library (Keyboard Hooks)

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard, hotkeys

I try to configure some global Hotkeys in a C# WinForm Application that should work with and without focus. For this I played a little bit with some Hooking Librarys like: [Link](http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/)

But these Libraries are not working really reliable so that I decided to look for a different way. And I found one but there is one problem: With the new method posted below I can catch a keypress, but I like to catch also the keydown (WM_KEYDOWN/0x100) and keyup event... But this is not working. Any ideas?

Code:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vk);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);



            const int MOD_CONTROL = 0x0002;
            const int MOD_SHIFT = 0x0004;
            const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x0312;
            const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // Hook Keys
            RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 1, MOD_CONTROL, (int)0);
            RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 2, MOD_CONTROL, (int)Keys.X);

        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            UnregisterHotKey(this.Handle, 1);
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY && (int)m.WParam == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("here");
            }
            if (m.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN && (int)m.WParam == 2)
                this.Opacity = 100;
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
```

Comment: I don't think `RegisterHotkey` is the correct API for the task in hand. You know, if you're looking for a reliable API for registering global hotkeys you might enjoy my open source project: https://github.com/ByteBlast/Shortcut

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried it with your Code. But it seems you have the same problem like all the others Hook Libraries. With some Applications it is not working. For example the Hotkeys are not working in Word2010 or VisualStudio2012. If you have one of these applications in foreground the hotkeys get not fired... Any ideas? I really need a global System Hotkey function...

Comment: And your library also does not support keydown and keyup events or? Because I could not find it...

Comment: that's quite peculiar. does the problem apply for ALL hotkey combinations or only combinations that Visual Studio and Word are currently using? Because for example, my screen capture utility uses the "PrtScreen" hotkey and it works fine even with VS in the foreground.